# How can i parse document.write/response.write to use single quotes instead of double quotes for AngleSharp?

Tags: anglesharp

I'm working with old **html(ASP) files** and i need to convert/parse them to work with new browsers.

I'm using AngleSharp, my problem is when it tries to parse ***response*** and ***document.write*** that uses single quotes for it's values and AngleSharp parse it to double quotes.

**Input**

```
Response.Write ("<input type=text name=attrname value='" + sVar + "'>");
```

**Output (AngleSharp)**

```
Response.Write ("<input type="text" name="attrname" value="&quot; + sVar + &quot;">");
```

**Output expected**

```
Response.Write ("<input type='text' name='attrname' value='" + sVar + "'>");
```

Is there a way to skip parsing or set a different formating for both? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The serialization is done by an `IMarkupFormatter`. By default, this formatter uses double quotes for the attributes (as the formatter does not know that you are inside some ASP code where you use double quotes on the outside).

Easiest way would be to roll your own formatter (example):

```cs
class MyMarkupFormatter : HtmlMarkupFormatter
{
    protected override string Attribute(IAttr attr)
    {
        return $"{attr.Name}='{attr.Value}'";
    }
}
```

You could use it like this:

```cs
var config = Configuration.Default;
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
var input = "<input type=text name=attrname value='\" + sVar + \"'>";
var document = await context.OpenNewAsync();
var formatter = new MyMarkupFormatter();
document.Body.InnerHtml = input;
document.Body.FirstChild.ToHtml(formatter).Dump(); // <input type='text' name='attrname' value='" + sVar + "'>
```

Note that the implementation of `Attribute` is only so simple for illustration purposes. You should handle more cases (and potentially take care of transforming contained single quotes etc.).